# How can I test the value of a column for each row?

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have a dataframe with 10 columns and around 20,000,000 rows.
I need to compare the values of the 10 columns row by row and create five columns with the new values. To do this, I defined a function consisting of an if function and applied it to test each.

For example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5], 'b':[11,12,13,14,16], 'c':[21,22,23,24,25], 'd':[31,32,33,34,35])


>>> def cal1(row):
>>>     v1=0
>>>     v2=0
>>>     if 0< row['a'] <2:
>>>         v1=1
>>>     if 11< row['b'] <14:
>>>         v2=1
>>>     return v1+v2


>>> def cal2(row):
>>>     v1=0
>>>     v2=0
>>>     if 2<= row['a'] <4:
>>>         v1=-1
>>>     if 14<= row['b']<=16:
>>>         v2=-1
>>>     return v1+v2    

>>> df['n1'] = df.apply(ca11, axis=1)
>>> df['n2'] = df.apply(cal2, axis=1)
```

I was able to get the answer this way, but I needed five defined functions, each with a long list of conditions. And the calculation was too slow.
(Actual data should be tested on all 10 columns, with at least 10 conditions.)

Is there a better way to test the data in each column row by row than this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you have consistent values you want to assign to each row.  For example, `n1` is either `0`, `1`, or `2`.  If that's the case, you can just start `n1` at `0` and add with indexing:

```
df['n1'] = 0

mask1 = df.a.between(0, 2, inclusive=False) 
mask2 = df.b.between(11, 14, inclusive=False)

df.loc[mask1 | mask2, 'n1'] = 1
df.loc[mask1 & mask2, 'n1'] = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

`apply()` accepts several [parameters](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html): `func` and also `args`, which are

> Positional arguments to pass to function in addition to the array/series

You could could pass in e.g. `(0, 2, 11, 14)` to allow a more generic function to score column A, `(2, 4, 14, 16)` for column B, and so on. Alternatively, pass in the column name and let the function make decisions based on that.

There's a fair amount of CPU overhead and memory footprint to process 20 M rows. You might find it more performant to read each row to be scored using a [csvreader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and emit the result with a csvwriter, and have pandas import the augmented CSV file.